# SSRS- Conditional formatting with Percents and numbers

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, formatting, numbers

In my mind this should be easy.. I have spent a good bit of time trying to get this right

Problem-
I have 1 data set that returns whole numbers as well as percents. What I am looking for is a formatting step to work and add the correct suffix (x100+% when % or nothing)

Here is what I have but don't get consistent results

```
=iif(Fields!Mid_Size.Value<1,Format(Fields!Mid_Size.Value,"P"),Format(Fields!Mid_Size.Value,"#"))
```

The raw data looks like:

```
Alpha   Mid-Size
11      49
0.0718954248366013  0.320261437908497
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you want decimals on any of it?  Also, can you give an example of what the above would look like if it was correct?  I can probably help you out with this.

Comment: Ideally I would want no decimals.  So 
    Alpha    MidSize
    11            15   55%       23%

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=iif(Fields!Mid_Size.Value<1,FormatPercent(Fields!Mid_Size.Value,0),Format(Fields!Mid_Size.Value,"#"))
```

This uses the `FormatPercent` function.  The '0' is for no decimal places; you can set that to however many you want.

Comment: I tried that but found my column with .60 is showing up as 660%. Everything else appears fine

Comment: Also- Any ideas how to check if something is a decimal vs full number? zeros are coming up as % in whole number fields

Comment: Interesting... .60 should come up as 60%  I'm not sure why that would occur.  You could change the first iif statement to have `Fields!Mid_Size.Value < 1 AND Fields!Mid_Size.Value <> 0`

Comment: agreed. I put the same column side by side with different formatting and Its very odd. Even tried the reversed formatting of the iif and same result

Comment: Well, you could go by my philosophy: `Kludge it 'till it works`.  `iif(Fields!Mid_Size.Value = .6, "60%", ...`

Comment: I have been trying that. Still not having any predictable or consistent results :/

Comment: Hmm... I'd have to see more to troubleshoot.  That's really weird.